# materailize css side nav is not navigating

Tags: javascript, css, material-design

```html
<div class="navbar-fixed">

  <nav class="nav-wrapper indigo ">

    <a href=" #home"> <img src="images/logo.png" class="responsive-img logo "></a>
    <a href="#" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="side-link">
      <i class="material-icons white-text">menu</i>
    </a>
    <ul class="navigation hide-on-med-and-down right">
      <li>
        <a href="#home"><strong class="white-text text-lighten-1 active">Home</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#facts"><strong class="white-text text-lighten-1 active">Facts</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#symtoms"><strong class="white-text text-lighten-1 active">Symtoms</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#statistics"><strong class="white-text text-lighten-1 active">Statistics</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#precautions"><strong class="white-text text-lighten-1 active">Precautions</strong></a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#myths"><strong class="white-text text-lighten-1 active">Myths</strong></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>

<ul class="sidenav indigo" id="side-link">
  <li>
    <a href="#home1" class="white-text  active">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#symtoms1" class="white-text  active">Symtoms</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#statistics" class="white-text  active">Statistics</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#precautions" class="white-text active ">Precautions</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#facts1" class="white-text active ">Facts</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#myths" class="white-text active ">myths</a>
  </li>
</ul>

</header>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidenav').sidenav();
});
```

Comment: What Framework?

Comment: materailize css,   scrollspy is also not working properly seems there is some issue in javascript

Comment: some issue in javascript ?  Can you show us some error from console log?

Comment: sorry no issues in javascript just checked